# How to debug a crash with Java Result: error_code

Tags: java, jna

I have a Java application that uses a C++ DLL via JNA. The C++ DLL is proprietary, therefore, I cannot share the code unless I can make a simplified reproducible example. It is not straight forward to make a reproducible example until I further debug.

The application crashes sporadically with the error message `Java Result: -1073740940`. I am running the Java application from Netbeans, although it crashes without Netbeans. Since there is no *hs_err_.log*, I guess crash is in the C++ layer. How can I begin debug this crash?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section titled _"Help others reproduce the problem"_.

Comment: What DLL? Which function/method is crashing? Is it a C or C++ method? Does it crash without using NetBeans?  When/how is the error message produced?   "How can I debug" starts with narrowing down the problem to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: C++ dll is a multi-threaded network application. It crashes with or without NetBeans. I am afraid I do not have a minimal reproducible code. In the NetBeans console, it shows `Java Result: -1073740940`. I would like to know how can I get more information about the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Java Result" output from Netbeans simply tells you the exit code of the java program. You could generate the same with a `System.exit(-1073740940);`. A successful program exits with a code of 0. Anything else is a failure that requires documentation to interpret.

You have not given us any indication what DLL you are using, so the only information we have to work with is this exit code.  Converting that int to hex digits results in `0xc0000374` which you can enter into your favorite search engine and find out is a [Heap Corruption Exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2015/01/30/heap-corruption-exception-0xc0000374/). Some examples are provided but in general this means you are accessing non-allocated native memory.

Without having any idea what code you're using, I would guess you're doing something wrong with native memory, invoking native functions, or incorrectly manipulating pointers or handles somewhere in your application.

You should start by looking closely at arguments to native functions.  Type mapping could be a problem if the number of bytes is mismatched.  Investigate any `Pointer`-based arguments to native functions, including `ByReference` arguments.  Trace back in the code and find when/how these Pointers were associated with native-allocated memory.  If it was never allocated, that's one possibility for the problem.  If it was allocated, see if you can find a point where that memory was freed, possibly by a different native function.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. The C++ DLL is proprietary stuff and JNA mapping code is inherited. Therefore, I cannot share the code unless I can make a simplified reproducible example. It is not straight forward to make a reproducible example for such kind of memory corruption issue. However, I am working on it.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the crash was *heap corruption* in the C++ layer. If a random crash occurs due to heap corruption, sometimes, it is complicated to pinpoint the cause of crash because the crash can happen later, when the program tries to manipulate the corrupted memory. Hence, it is also complicated to provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), especially when we work on the proprietary legacy code.

**How I debugged this crash:**

- *Reproduction:* Try to find a consistent use case for the crash. If the crash is random then try to figure out a set of user actions that always leads to the crash.
- *Assumption:* Guess which feature/component contains the crash.
- *Validation:* Make sure that crash is not happening when you disable this feature/component.
- *Verification*: Skimm through and slice the code. Review the small piece of code.
- *Documentation*: Write everything.

Daniel's answer was very helpful in fixing this crash!